# How to get the list of all cities name from the 200km radius of area from the current location's latitude and longitude in android?

Tags: android, gps, location

in android once we get the current location address latitude and longitude then after how we can able to get the list of all the nearby cities name within the 200kms radius of current location , i.e if my current location latitude and longitudes are 23.00 & 72.50 respectivity so on base of that how can i get the list of all cities nearby this location address within the 200 kms radius?

Answer (score 0):

You can use google place API for this, please check it.

Comment: i have tried to search on the "Google Location Api" but still i dont get any sample code which can able to get me the location information with some specific radius of kilometers i.e with radius of 200 kms , pl anybody provide me any spacific example which can able to provide the nearby location information from the current location.